# How can i connect to local advantage database using pyodbc in python?

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc, advantage-database-server

As far as i can understand to use pyodbc you have to

```
 cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Advantage ODBC Driver};SERVER=local;DataDirectory=\\AltaDemo\Demo\AltaPoint.add;DATABASE=AltaPoint;UID=admin;PWD=admin;ServerTypes=1;')
 cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

This is the error i get from the console when i run this
Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the driver is `Advantage StreamlineSQL ODBC`, so the bare minimum connect string is:

```
DRIVER={Advantage StreamlineSQL ODBC};DataDirectory=D:\Temp
```

Other optinal options are:

```
DefaultType=Advantage
User ID=xxx
Password=xxx
ServerTypes=2
AdvantageLocking=ON
CharSet=ANSI
Language=ANSI
Description=My ADS connection
Locking=Record
MaxTableCloseCache=25
MemoBlockSize=64
Rows=False
Compression=Internet
CommType=TCP_IP
TLSCertificate=     
TLSCommonName=
TLSCiphers=
DDPassword=Dictionary Password
EncryptionType=
FIPS=False
TrimTrailingSpaces=True
SQLTimeout=600
RightsChecking=OFF
```

If you want to use the Local Server you have to pass `ServerTypes=1` like you already have in your original string.

For more options and documentation see also:

- [The official documentation](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/odbc_odbc_data_source_keys.htm)
- [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sybase-advantage/)