# ODBC Call Failed between Access 2010 and Advantage database server Over a network

Tags: ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2010, advantage-database-server, dsn

First and Foremost, I know zip, zilch, nada, about VBA, access, and Advantage database Server.

I have a PC in one location that can connect and update with an Access 2010 file where every drive is mapped, e.g. \file\whatever

The advantage streamlinesql odbc dsn's were setup as such \file\whatever foxpro

Now, the PC has been moved to a new location (the company moved) and there is a vpn connection between the two locations (the data server is still located in the old location and cannot be moved), and so the new map would look like this: \xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\file\whatever

However, Access cannot connect so that it can run its process and update the files it needs to.

I do not know the actual code to place here to help with fixing this, so answering this question with more is fine with me.

I can say that the vpn is built with sonic wall.

Comment: You mentioned VBA, is there any VBA code that you could share with us?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is to connect with ARC32 (The ADS query tool), since you can then rule out ODBC and Access as the problem.

ADS has three connection types:

- local
- remote
- internet

When you directly connect to an Advantage Database Server via TCP/IP, you want the `remote` connection type.

The connection type can usually be set via the `ads.ini` file, which also **must** contain the IP address and port for the ADS server:

```
[SETTINGS]
ADS_SERVER_TYPE=2

[MYDATABASE]
LAN_IP=10.20.1.20
LAN_PORT=6262
```

For more info about ADS.ini see the official documentation:

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage12/master_ads_ini_file_support.htm

When you try connection over ODBC maybe a complete reference of the connection options would be useful, I have written them down here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33544131/426242

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply (I apologize, had been on vacation). It looks like Advantage itself can be accessed no problem. Access runs into the problem when trying to run the query and adding information to a table.

Comment: Access is not my area of expertise, so all I can say now is: "good luck". Maybe somebody else can help you.